# What is this icon is notification bar?

Tags: notifications, notification-icons

I can’t work out the icon on the top left, the message with a cross through it.

Any ideas?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What happens if you pull down the notification tray to see the full notification?

Answer (score 0):

That means you've got a text message stuck. Either incoming or outgoing. I don't know what version of android you have or what phone so it doesn't help much. It could be that you have data turned off so you can't receive or send a MMS.